# Why does avr-gcc exit with status 1?

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded, eclipse-cdt, avr

I’ve just set up Eclipse Neon 3 on Windows 10 to use it for programming AVR microcontroller ATMEGA32, I’ve installed WinAVR and the AVR plugins, and I have also configured AVRDUDE for uploading the code to my target hardware, Everything seems to be okay except that I keep getting this annoying error  whenever I attempt to compile any code. For example, I’ve been trying to compile this simple code, but the same error pops out.

```
ERROR MESSAGE:
12:39:06 ** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project flasher **
make all 
Building file: ../main.c
Invoking: AVR Compiler
avr-gcc -Wall -Os -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -std=gnu99 -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -mmcu=atmega32 -DF_CPU=8000000UL -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -c -o "main.o" "../main.c"
make: * [main.o] Error 1

12:39:06 Build Finished (took 395ms)
```

I’ve tried reinstalling eclipse and also uninstalled avast antivirus and deactivated windows defender because i read that antivirus may consider .o files as a threat, but that still doesn't work.

NOTE: I’ve tried compiling the same code on a friend’s computer with the same version of eclipse and the same compiler and it was compiled successfully.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i = 0;

  DDRD &= ~(1<<PD2);
  DDRD |= (1<<PD5);

  while(1)
  {

    if(PIND&(1<<2))
    {
      PORTD |= (1<<5);
    }
    else
    {
      PORTD &= ~(1<<5);
    }

   }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a linker error, not a compiler error. Which is the normal, every day state of affairs when using Eclipse. Some path somewhere is broken and the IDE fails to relay this information properly. Dig through Eclispe paths for a week or so. Try to find out what exactly is passed on to `gcc -I`. Alternatively uninstall Eclipse and get a better IDE that allows you to be productive.

Comment: As a side note, `int main (void)` doesn't make sense on a freestanding system. Return to where? You should use `void main (void)` and compile with `-ffreestanding`.

Comment: `int main (void)` is completely fine here, and **`-ffreestanding` doesn't gain you anything except disabling some optimizations**.  On the other hand, GCC is smart enough to optimize out the final `return 0` because that code is unreachable. Apart from that, the error in the question is with almost certanty not related to hosted vs. freestanding.